# AngularJs Server side validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, server-side

I am using angularjs to submit a really simple form... 
I must insert a numeric code in my form. The code must be validate server side, calling an external service. When I get the promise I would like to check either the code was correct or not.
If the code is not correct I would like to set a red border in the textbox and show a message... here the html

```
<input name="code" type="text" style="width:155px;" data-ng-model="Codice" 
    data-ng-required="true" data-ng-pattern="/^(\d){22}$/" data-ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'mousedown blur' }" />

<span data-ng-show="myform.code.$error.pattern" class="error">Codice non valido</span>
```

Now I let you see what I do in my controller

```
if (response.Result == "1")
{
   myform.code.$error.pattern = true;
}
```

In this way I just see the message but the the border of the textbox remain black... so I have tryed:

```
if (response.Result == "1")
{
   myform.code.$setValidity('mismatch',false);
}
```

But in this way, even if I modify the code, the model remain "not valid" so I cannot do a post anymore...

Any solution?
Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html create one span for custom validation

```
 <span class="help-block" ng-show="myform.name.$error.ntValidName">Not valid name</span>
```

And in controller set the validity like this,if not valid then

```
 myform.name.$setValidity("ntValidName", false);
```

This way you can create your custom validation

Comment: Thank you.. I was wrong in the validation name... in the controller I called it "mismatch".. in the view "pattern"

Comment: Ya I saw that But i thought that you html code you are displaying is for first condition and you might have modified your html for 2nd case.

Comment: I wanted to use just one span... but think is much better use two different span like you did...